# How can I run a Kotlin's maven project which using IDEA and don't using .m2 repository?

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

guys. I want to using IDEA to create a Kotlin's maven project.My maven repository is not the default location which is .m2. When I maven import,it using the location which I set, but when I build the project, the IDEA want to using /home/$USER/.m2/repository to search the jar.How can I fixed it?

```
Warning:Kotlin: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: /home/wfb/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
Error:(3, 16) Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.Array'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library
```

I try to using terminal to run it and It doesn't have problems. When Using IDEA to run it , the tips like above

Comment: Try version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.1+latest+builds Also try to set the `MAVEN_REPOSITORY` path in Settings (Preferences on macOS) |  | Appearance & Behavior | **Path Variables** settings.

Answer (score 0):

1) Preferences > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Maven

2) Check "Override" near "Local Repository" and input the path to your Maven local  repository

P.S. I'm using IDEA 2018.3, so on other versions the path to this setting might slightly differ

Comment: Yes, I override this, that's why I can import the jars correctly. But when I build the kotlin project, the IDEA want to use the .m2 to search the jars. If this is a Java Project, it can do correctly.